How to back up samba running on proxmox?
I have proxmox running a VM with Ubuntu server + samba share, the share folder itself is on a separate drive.
My question is the way to back up VM and all the files on a share?
I can back proxmox VM using proxmox's back up capabilities. But do I need to back up samba share folder separately? Or backuping the VM is enough?
I'm sorry I'm not that experienced, that's why I'm asking what the approach you would have taken.

What step in the backup process of Samba are you stuck on exactly? Instead of asking what the "best way" to backup Samba share is, specify what steps of the process you are unable to complete, and provide enough information for us to diagnose the reason you are having a problem. Questions seeking the "best way" is seeking an opinion on how to do something which will more than often be closed.

To expand a little on Ramhound's correct advice: "Best advice" depends on a myriad of factors, not all of which are quantifiable, and definitely not all of which are included here in your rather bare-bones question. There are factors unique to your situation which may make one solution better than another generally good solution, which may not be true for someone else. There isn't one "always best" answer for everyone. This is a big reason why we avoid "best way" questions. Instead, tell us the direction you're going already, what you've tried, where it's gone wrong, and give a specific Q.

Thank you for answering! I'm sorry for my poor question. Since I'm not experienced Im asking the way you would do it. Do you back up VM or VM + samba share
? Or backupping the VM is enough?

Is the share inside the VM? There's usually nothing special about it in that case; it's just a folder that's part of the VM.

When I backup the VM I get 250G file but the share is empty. Maybe I need to back up the share separately?
